# How to know the SAP oubound delivery item is posted in a GR

Tags: abap, badi

What tables to look at to check whether the `outbound delivery item` is posted in a `GR`?

Or is there any BADI that can provide this information?

Comment: Could you please elaborate the scenario? Usually an outbound delivery is posted in a GI, not a GR. Is it a return order maybe?

Comment: badi are used not for providing information, but for altering system behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can get the delivery (or delivery items) status from tables

- `VBUK` (header status)
- `VBUP` (items status)

for example:

```
DATA: ls_vbup type vbup.

SELECT SINGLE * FROM VBUP 
 WHERE VBELN = <delivery no> 
   AND POSNR = <delivery item> 
  INTO ls_vbup.
```

`LS_VBUP-WBSTA` is the Goods movement status for the delivery. It can contain:

- `C`: status goods movement "completed". All the quantity has been
  posted
- `A`: status goods movement "open". No quantity has been posted yet
- `B`: status goods moviment "partial".

Otherwise if you also want to know which GR/GI has been posted for your delivery you could check the SD document flow table `VBFA`:

```
DATA: lt_vbfa TYPE TABLE OF vbfa.

SELECT * FROM VBFA
 WHERE VBELV = <delivery no>
   AND POSNV = <delivery item>
   AND VBTYP_V = 'J'  " J means Delivery
   AND VBTYP_N = 'R'  " R means Goods movement
 INTO TABLE lt_vbfa.
```

`LT_VBFA` table contains the GR/GI posted for your delivery

Comment: Hi @manuel_b could you please advise what is the difference between LFSTA and WBSTA in the table VBUP?

Comment: Useful informations about a field meaning can be found in the documentation of the data element. In particular: LFSTA=The status line tells you if the item is not yet delivered, is partly delivered, is completely delivered, or is not relevant for delivery, WBSTA=The status shows if a goods issue or receipt has taken place for a delivery item. VBUP/VBUK tables contain the status off several kind of SD documents; LFSTA is relevant for sales order for example (a SO has been delivered or not), while WBSTA is relevant for deliveries (a delivery has been GI/GR posted or not)